# Buy vs Build - Internal Analytics for a Web App Behind a Paywall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, analytics, chartbeat

I am looking to track analytics for our web app. User accounts sit behind a paywall. Some basic questions I want to answer are time on site, most used sections of the app, where they are running in to problems...click tracking would be nice.

Is there a product out there that can track this data for my application? It is built on Ruby on Rails.

Searched G, Stackoverflow, looked everywhere for a good solution. Would love to hear some insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), it's in PHP and simple to setup. If PHP is an option for you, it's the way to go.

Comment: That's a possible. Does the basics.